# In SonarQube Dashboard, Assigning Issues taking a long time

Tags: sonarqube

**NOTE**: This was posted originally on the SonarQube User Mailing List which is now shutdown, so moving it here.

I have a SonarQube 5.0.1 installation.  It takes a long time for a user to edit an issue from the Web Dashboard (for example assign an issue) even when there are no analysis jobs running. I turned on server logging to "FULL" and noticed that the main time was getting consumed as shown below between inserting the record into issue_changes and the following select issue query. It seems to be waiting and polling for some notifications.

Here are the log entries:

```
2015.05.28 14:18:02 INFO  http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000-exec-2 web[sql]  15ms Executed SQL: update issues set action_plan_key=?, severity=?, manual_severity=?, ...
2015.05.28 14:18:02 INFO  http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000-exec-2 web[sql]  0ms Executed SQL: INSERT INTO issue_changes (kee, issue_key, user_login, change_type, change_data, ...
2015.05.28 14:18:38 INFO  pool-5-thread-1 web[sql]  0ms Executed SQL: select id, data from notifications order by id asc limit ? - parameters are: <1>
2015.05.28 14:19:38 INFO  pool-5-thread-1 web[sql]  0ms Executed SQL: select id, data from notifications order by id asc limit ? - parameters are: <1>
2015.05.28 14:20:38 INFO  pool-5-thread-1 web[sql]  0ms Executed SQL: select id, data from notifications order by id asc limit ? - parameters are: <1>
2015.05.28 14:20:53 INFO  pool-2-thread-3 web[sql]  171370ms Executed SQL: select i.kee,root.uuid,i.updated_at,i.action_plan_key,i.assignee,i.effort_to_fix,i.issue_attributes,...
2015.05.28 14:20:53 INFO  pool-2-thread-3 web[bulk]  15ms ES bulk request for [Action 'UpdateRequest' for key '9b985185-349f-48a8-9762-21ec952c66ea' on index 'issues' on type 'issue'],
2015.05.28 14:20:53 INFO  pool-2-thread-3 web[refresh]  63ms ES refresh request on indices 'issues'
2015.05.28 14:20:53 INFO  http-bio-0.0.0.0-9000-exec-2 web[get]  0ms ES get request for key 'intellijinspection:ConstantConditions' on index 'rules' on type 'rule'
```

Additional Volume Information:  I have about 17 projects each having 22 modules, a total of 3M Lines of Code Each and 200K Issues each.

**UPDATE**:

So after some digging through the code, I understand that the following gets called when the user edits a save and this causes the indexing to be done in-place.  Hence the time consumed reported against the select query above as iteration and indexing happens over its result-set.

```
ServerIssueStorage {

    ....

    @Override
    protected void doAfterSave() {
        indexer.index();
    }

}
```

I guess this one of the reasons why SQ team cautions upgrading to 5.* versions if you have and issue count > 5M.

Any idea when the releases will start supporting this volume?  Is there any workaround at the cost of something else that can alleviate this issue until then?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed in version 5.0 overall performances can be impacted by the number of parallel analysis (continuous inspection scheduled on multiple jenkins slaves for instance). This limitation was improved in 5.1 and effort is being continued in 5.2.

Comment: Simon, any plan as to when the 5M threshold limitation would be eliminated?  I have about 4.4M issues now as I have been adding analysis of more branches recently and intend to add some more.  Incidentally, I have edited my post to clarify that the slow down is seen even when no analysis jobs are running.

Comment: This is only a recommendation. There's no configured limit. With versions 5.0 and 5.1 it's up to you to evaluate the overall performances when having dozens of millions issues.